# Derivative of a matrix-vector multiplication with respect to the matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, tensors

Let's assume that we have $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.
I want to show that $\frac{\partial(\textbf{Ax})}{\partial\textbf{A}} = \textbf{x}^T$, e.g. in [0], where we have:

$$\frac{\partial\textbf{W}_3\textbf{x}_2}{\partial\textbf{W}_3} = \textbf{x}_2^T$$

for $\frac{\partial E}{\partial\textbf{W}_3}$. As far as I understand, we have $\textbf{Ax} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, so in reality we differentiate the vector with respect to the matrix, what gives us a tensor with its 3D representation. I'm not sure how this can be equal to $\textbf{x}^T$.

---

[0] Sudeep Raja, [A derivation of backpropagation in matrix form](https://sudeepraja.github.io/Neural/), August 17, 2016.

Comment: Where in the GitHub page is the claim?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo What GitHub page ?

Comment: https://sudeepraja.github.io/Neural/

Comment: "Backpropagation equations can be derived by repeatedly applying the chain rule. First we derive these for the weights in $W_3$:"

Comment: Have you considered contacting the author directly? Doctoral student, not professor.

Comment: To be frank no, because I thought it was quite popular formula (I certainly saw it in other sources)

Comment: These deep learning tutorials are written by barbarians. It's not the first time I encounter such barbarism in differentiation.

Comment: Have you read the comment section on the GitHub page?

Comment: I've just read the comment section, but I don't think that there's any comment that addresses my issue.